# Identifying lines ending in capital letters with AWK and using them as record separators

Tags: awk

This is a smaller representative version of a data file that I need to parse and divide into chunks with awk based on the roman numeral of each chunk.

```
I                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   Apple                                                                                                                                                                                             
   II                                                                                                                                                                                                
Banana                                                                                                                                                                                               

   III                                                                                                                                                                                               
   Mango                                                                                                                                                                                             
IV                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Durian                                                                                                                                                                                               
Lemon                                                                                                                                                                                                

   IV                                                                                                                                                                                                
      Papaya                                                                                                                                                                                         
       V
```

This seemed like an easy task with awk, so I tried 
`gawk -v RS="[A-Z]+$" '{print $0}' blah.txt` to use lines that end with one or more capital letters (thus indicating lines with Roman Numerals) as record separators.

Surprisingly the program outputted the entire data file. Where did I go wrong?
Even more surprisingly, if I place an `exit` after the print statement, it *still* prints the entire file (indicating that the whole file is considered as *one* record)

I am using GNU AWK 4.1.3 on a Linux Mint machine.

**NOTE:** The specific use case I have in mind is to extract an arbitrary Shakespearean sonnet by number from the text file at http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1041/pg1041.txt (after removing the boilerplate header and footer data )

Comment: The text on the website looks more structured than your test case - why not skip the top part and print every second paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` is the culprit - GNU awk treats the entire file as a single string for the purpose of matching a `RS` regular expression, and `$` thus only matches at the end of the file (This is [noted in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/gawk-split-records.html#gawk-split-records)). Try replacing it with `\>`, which matches end of word, not end of string (And `\<` to match the start of a word, so that only things like I and IV are matched):

```
$ awk -v RS='\\<[A-Z]+\\>' '{print $0}' input.txt 


   Apple                                                                                                                                                                                             


Banana                                                                                                                                                                                               



   Mango                                                                                                                                                                                             


Durian                                                                                                                                                                                               
Lemon                                                                                                                                                                                                



      Papaya
```

You'll have to deal with all the extra newlines and whitespace, of course.

Comment: Could you explain why $ failed? Accoding to the pattern suggested by the file it is supposed to match the end of the line

Comment: @smilingbuddha `$` matches end of string, not end of line. The entire file is treated as one string when it comes to splitting into records. Plus your sample has a ton of spaces at the end of each line.

Answer (score 2):

Given the input on http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1041/pg1041.txt, it looks like you can just print the 12th, 14th, 16th, paragraph to get the output that you want. Setting the Record Separator to an empty string and printing the desired record is enough to do that.

For example, to print the first sonnet:

```
$ awk -v RS='' -v sonnet=1 'NR == 10 + 2 * sonnet' file
  From fairest creatures we desire increase,
  That thereby beauty's rose might never die,
  But as the riper should by time decease,
  His tender heir might bear his memory:
  But thou, contracted to thine own bright eyes,
  Feed'st thy light's flame with self-substantial fuel,
  Making a famine where abundance lies,
  Thy self thy foe, to thy sweet self too cruel:
  Thou that art now the world's fresh ornament,
  And only herald to the gaudy spring,
  Within thine own bud buriest thy content,
  And tender churl mak'st waste in niggarding:
    Pity the world, or else this glutton be,
    To eat the world's due, by the grave and thee.
```

Comment: Ah that's a good point! But for this question specifically I was more curious why my particular awk regexp failed. Which is why I've accepted the other answer, even though your answers my original task of extracting an arbitrary sonnet more succinctly.